# OxyPlot AreaSeries does not work horizontally

Tags: wpf, plot, series, oxyplot

I use `AreaSeries` from `OxyPlot` to plot vertical `AreaSeries`.

I apply a method that builds from a list different color `AreaSeries`. Here is the code:

```
private static void AddTriggerAreaSeries(PlotModel plotModel, int initialPoint, int endingPoint, int index)
        {
            var seriesArea = new AreaSeries();

            seriesArea.Title = "Instruction";
            seriesArea.Color = OxyColors.Transparent;
            seriesArea.Fill = TriggerColorList[index];

            //Draws vertically from bottom to top (0 -> 20)  
            //j referes to the second axis, the y axis in this case (vertical axis)     
            //The initial and ending points represent interval limits in which the area series is drawn

            for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(initalPoint, j));
            }
            for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(endingPoint, j));
            }
            plotModel.Series.Add(seriesArea);
        }
```

See picture below [image: Verical area series]

The code works for `vertical series`. However when I try to plot the same thing horizontally it will not plot from an interval that I give.

Here is a sample of the code I use to plot the `AreaSeries horizontally`:

```
        // Basically same code that I used but calling seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(x, y)) reversed, such that the line goes in the x direction
        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(j, initalPoint));
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(j, endingPoint));
        }
        plotModel.Series.Add(seriesArea);
```

Here is a picture of the outcome of this code
In this example the `initialPoint=1` and `endingPoint=2`. I try to draw the `interval [1,2]`, instead only it draws from `interval [0,1]` and for the ending point draws just a line:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I changed the orientation of the plot and made the `AreaSeries` vertical.

Here is how it looks in the end:
[image: Horizontal bar]
Here is the code:
(I use MVVM pattern, I create a PlotModel withing a class than apply mothods to it)

```
private static void CreateColorBar(PlotModel plotModel, HemodynamicsMapping hemodynamicsMapping)
        {
            plotModel.InvalidatePlot(false);

            plotModel.Series.Clear();
            plotModel.Axes.Clear();

            // x axis
            plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Right,
                AbsoluteMaximum = 10,
                Minimum = 0,
                AbsoluteMinimum = 0,
                Maximum = 10,
                MajorTickSize = 0,
                MinorTickSize = 0,
                TextColor = OxyColors.Transparent
            });

            // y axis 
            plotModel.Axes.Add(new LinearAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                AbsoluteMaximum = 61,
                AbsoluteMinimum = 0,
                Maximum = 61,
                Minimum = 0,
                MajorTickSize = 0,
                MinorTickSize = 0,
                TextColor = OxyColors.Transparent
            });

            // z axis 
            // I only use this axis to show the labels you see in the picture
            plotModel.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis
            {
                Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,
                AbsoluteMaximum = 8,
                AbsoluteMinimum = 0,
                Maximum = 8,
                Minimum = 0,
                MajorTickSize = 0,
                MinorTickSize = 0
            });

            var count = 0;
            //Adds series with colors form black to green
            for (var i = 3; i > 0; i--)
            {
                for (var j = 9; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    AddColorBarArea(plotModel, i, j, hemodynamicsMapping, count, -1);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            //Adds green series 
            AddColorBarArea(plotModel, 1, 0, hemodynamicsMapping, count, 1);

            //Adds series with colors form green to white
            for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    AddColorBarArea(plotModel, i, j, hemodynamicsMapping, count, 1);
                    count++;
                }
            }

            plotModel.InvalidatePlot(true);
        }

        // Adds a series to the plot. There are 61 series since there are 61 colors.
        private static void AddColorBarArea(PlotModel plotModel,int i, int j, HemodynamicsMapping hemodynamicsMapping, int count, int negative)
        {
            var seriesArea = new AreaSeries();

            for (var k = 0; k < 500; k++)
            {
                seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(count, k));
            }
            for (var k = 0; k < 500; k++)
            {
                seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(count + 1, k));
            }

            seriesArea.Color = hemodynamicsMapping.ChannelColor(j, i, negative).ToOxyColor();
            seriesArea.Fill = hemodynamicsMapping.ChannelColor(j, i, negative).ToOxyColor();

            plotModel.Series.Add(seriesArea);
        }
```

However, the ideal position of this color bar should have been vertical, as I am tring to achieve something like this:
(here picture)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AreaSeries documentation](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/series/AreaSeries.html):

> A AreaSeries shows an area between two sets of points, or between a set of point and a baseline.

I have to admit that's not much to go off of, but it does indicate that there are two sets of points.  The `Points` property is one set and `Points2` is the other.  You're supposed to use them both (unless you intend to use the baseline).  Also, unless you want the area to be something other than a rectangle, I believe you only need two points for each set as follows (note: I didn't test this, but it's similar to code I have tested):

```
 seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(0, initialPoint));
 seriesArea.Points.Add(new DataPoint(19, initialPoint));
 seriesArea.Points2.Add(new DataPoint(0, endPoint));
 seriesArea.Points2.Add(new DataPoint(19, endPoint));
 
 plotModel.Series.Add(seriesArea);
```

Furthermore, if the AreaSeries still isn't working for you, you could try [RectangleAnnotation](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/annotations/RectangleAnnotation.html) or [PolygonAnnotation](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models/annotations/PolygonAnnotation.html)

Note: As of this writing, there is nothing documented for `RectangleAnnotaion` or `PolygonAnnotation` besides the fact that they exist.